# Get weired answer back from JSOn file

Tags: android, json, save

Hey Guys in this code I write a JSON File and after that I want to read it. But everytime I want read I get something back like this: "[B@ea6df". Everytime another answer. What I did wrong?

```
public void writeFile(Context context, String mJsonResponse) {
    String file_name = "login_datas.json";
    try {
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + file_name);
        file.write(mJsonResponse);
        file.flush();
        file.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error in Writing: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}

public void readFile(Context context) {
    try {
        String file_name = "login_datas.json";
        File f = new File(context.getFilesDir().getPath() + "/" + file_name);
        //check whether file exists
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
        int size = is.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer);
        is.close();
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,buffer.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Error in Reading: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buffer.toString()` does not do what you think. It does not write the content of the byte array but uses the generic `Object.toString()` method which just shows the class name of the object and its hash code in hexadecimal representation.

Comment: Can you give me a Exemple how Object.toString() Works?

Comment: An example is in your question "[B@ea6df" (the [B stands for an array of bytes, the "ea6df" is the hash code) Docu: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--